# Simulate a browser in Ruby, with cookies?

Tags: ruby, browser

It is possible to simulate a browser in Ruby? I know about OpenURI, but I want to simulate even the cookies behavior, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) is the way to go for basic things like simplifying interaction, holding onto cookies, etc.

For full browser simulation, though, including fancy things like Javascript, we're more limited. A tool like [Watir](http://watir.com/), however, can actually open up the browser and run it as your code dictates, which can sometimes be the only option if interacting with complex Javascript applications is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to execute javascript you could also try: [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb)

```
Curl::Easy.perform(uri) do |curl|
  curl.enable_cookies   = true
  curl.follow_location  = true
end
```